# Linearity of fourier series

Tags: fourier-analysis, fourier-series

I am given the following function:

$$ g(x) =
\begin{cases}
sin(\frac{\pi^2}{x}),  & x \in[-\pi,\pi),x\neq0 \\
0, & x=0
\end{cases}$$

It's fourier series is: $\sum_{n=1}^\infty b_nsin(nx)$

Now I am trying to find the fourier series of $f(x) :=g(x)+1$.

I want to say that the series is $1+\sum_{n=1}^\infty b_nsin(nx)$, but why is this allowed? I know that $\hat f(n)+\hat g(n) = \widehat {(f+g)}(n)$ ($\hat f(n)$ denotes the n fourier coeffiecient of f). But can I conclude that I am allowed to add the series ? or is it only allowed in case both of the series absolutely converge?

Edit:
Basically that I'm trying to prove is the following:

$$\sum_{n \in \Bbb Z} (\hat g(n)+1)e^{inx} = \sum_{n \in \Bbb Z} \hat g(n)e^{inx}+\sum_{n \in \Bbb Z}1e^{inx} = \sum_{n \in \Bbb Z}\hat g(n)e^{inx}+1$$

(The first quailty is what I don't get)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1 is orthogonal to all the terms $\sin(nx)$. In fact, it is one of the basis elements for Fourier series $\{1,\cos(nx),\sin(nx) \}$, which form an orthogonal basis.

Edit:
Your equations are incorrect. It should read as follows, with f(x)=1

\begin{equation}
\sum\widehat{(g+f)}e^{inx} 
=
\sum(\widehat{g}+\widehat{f})e^{inx} 
=
\sum\widehat{g}e^{inx} +\sum\widehat{f}e^{inx} 
=
\sum b_n \sin(nx) + 1
\end{equation}

Note that the only nonzero Fourier coefficient of 1 is the constant term.

Comment: But It's still changing the order of series, isn't it? Isn't it only allowd in case both of the series absolutely converge?

Comment: But why is the second quality you wrote legal? you are splitting an infinite series into two series, and don't you need to know that the series absolutely converge in order to do that?

Comment: the second series only has 1 term, so either both sides converge or both sides diverge

Answer (score 0):

The type of Fourier series is no longer the same because you no longer have the same boundary condition. Accordingly you become forced to include a constant term as one of your basis functions. But unlike what you wrote, making this change does not add $1$ to each Fourier coefficient. It just adds in a term, say $\phi_0(x)=1$ so that $b_0=1$.